# Swift Communicating between view controllers

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, segue

I'm new to Swift and was wondering how I could set up segues between three view controllers. What I'm thinking is that the first viewController allows the user to choose between 2 objects, than redirects to secondView which allows to choose between 22 objects and based on the combination of the user's past 2 view controller choices, a new tableView is created. How can I trace the user's decisions and provide a tableView related to that in such a program? Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have Two rough solution for you.

1. (Not recommended) use two global variables VcOne and VcTwo. while selecting first object put a value in VcOne and when selecting from second 22 objects put value in VcTwo. and in tableView's Controller check both the variables and create your table View.
2. While performing Segue, have a Variable in destination ViewController and put a identifier. and have two variables on the Third ViewController. when you perform segue from second ViewController, assign Identifier of previous ViewController and current View Controller to next controller's Variables. and in tableView's Controller check both the variables and create your table View.
3. You can also use a array to keep track of user's selection.

Answer (score 0):

Those are very basics of iOS development. just split the tasks that you need to do.

First split steps you have to do. First study about the navigation between View Controllers. in your case using segue. There are lots of questions regarding that in stack overflow.

then find out how to pass data between viewControllers. once you know about navigation it is very easy.

You can create logic with the values you are passing recieving.
ex: firstViewController will pass parameter called `objectCount` to secondViewcontroller. and based on that value count you can decide what are objects should show hidden.

And then based on that selection you need to get Object back to the firstViewController or go to another 3rd View Controller.

Answer (score 0):

I'm really sorry but I don't think you can start developing iPhone application without understanding the basics.

You will need three ViewControllers and you need to use `parepare(for:sender:)` method to pass the data from one ViewController to another ViewController.

Here is an [example on how to pass data between ViewControllers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xTGCYT3OUhY).